# C# classes - basic example

Tags: c#, class

This is basically my first attempt to understand the classes in C#. I've went through several tutorials on the internet, but the thing I'm missing the most and what I haven't found anywhere yet, is a simple good example.

I have some idea how my basic program should look like and I would appreciate your help:

```
using System;

namespace Introduction_to_classes
{
    class Person
    {
        int Age;
        string Name;

        int DateOfBirth()
        {
            return 2013 - Age;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Person Mother = new Person(35, Alice);
            Person Son = new Person(12, Johny);

            Mother.Name = "Lucy";  // Just changing the value afterwards

            if(Mother.Age > Son.Age)
            {
                int year = Mother.DateOfBirth();
                Console.WriteLine("Mom was born in {0}.", year);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It's just an idea, it definitely doesn't work. But more than anything else it would help me if you can correct it to the working example...

Comment: In its current form this question isn't good and will likely get closed. Please focus on something specific you have trouble with.

Comment: You should ask about specific compilation errors that you get and do not know how to fix.

Comment: Public the members of `Person`; change the round braces to curly and name the members on instance creation. You've done. I posted the answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't understand the concept of classes at all. I know that for me the best way of understanding the basics is to see a correction of my work. I'm sorry if that doesn't meet the expectations of this site...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person(int age, string name)
    {
        Age = age;
        Name = name;
    }

    public int DateOfBirth()
    {
        return 2013 - Age;
    }
}

        class Program
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                Person Mother = new Person(35, "Alice");
                Person Son = new Person(12, "Johny");

                Mother.Name = "Lucy";  // Just changing the value afterwards

                if (Mother.Age > Son.Age)
                {
                    int year = Mother.DateOfBirth();
                    Console.WriteLine("Mom was born in {0}.", year);
                }
            }
        }
```

Some useful links: [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx)

Comment: I'd pay for such help! :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;

namespace Introduction_to_classes {
    class Person {
        public int Age;
        public string Name;

        public int DateOfBirth() {
            return 2013-Age;
        }
    }

    class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            Person Mother=new Person {
                Age=35,
                Name="Alice"
            };

            Person Son=new Person {
                Age=12,
                Name="Johny"
            };

            Mother.Name="Lucy";  // Just changing the value afterwards

            if(Mother.Age>Son.Age) {
                int year=Mother.DateOfBirth();
                Console.WriteLine("Mom was born in {0}.", year);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't 'think' that you can initialize fields that way.  I think they have to be properties.  But someone please correct me if I'm mistaken about that.

Comment: @BrandonMoore You can initialize fields, it's just that you typically shouldn't have public fields in the first place.

Comment: No suspecting. I've compiled the code as well.

Comment: @BrandonMoore You can initialize fields that way, but only as long as you have either not defined any constructors, or defined a constructor that takes 0 arguments. And you can only initialize public or internal fields that way (I think)

Comment: @KenKin Your answer helped me, thank you. I'm doing my best but as a beginner I do have troubles with the easy things...

Comment: @Jeyekomon: I have no argument on you. Just about the ***RULES***.

Comment: @KenKin If you're a typing monkey, then color me impressed.  Someone could make a looot of money off of you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're referring to a constructor that doesn't exist:

```
Person Mother = new Person(35, Alice);
```

The first argument here is an `int`, the second should be a `string` as far as I understand. But a string literal should be marked with double quotes, so that line should be:

```
Person Mother = new Person(35, "Alice");
```

Same for the following line.

Now you probably want a constructor that takes types of these arguments and you want to save these values to the new object, I assume. So, add this in your `Person` class:

```
public Person(int a, string n)
{
    this.Age = a;
    this.Name = n;
}
```

And, finally, you should make your `Age` and `Name` fields accessible to the other class, by marking them `internal` or `public`:

```
    public int Age;
    public string Name;
```

After that, you should be good to go.

Comment: Except that the `DatOfBirth` method and both fields are private.

Comment: @juharr I don't know for sure what's the default modifier for C# because I always specify them explicitly, but I *think* it's `internal`, not `private`. In this case, `internal` should be fine.

Comment: If it is outside of a class it's internal, inside it's private.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Comment: @juharr +1, you're absolutely correct. I've edited my answer to include this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: `new Person(35, "Alice")` implies that `class Person` defines a constructor `public Person(int age, string name)`. Alternatively, you'll have to call `new Person() { Age = 35, Name = "Alice" }` which only works as long as you have not defined a constructor, or have defined a constructor that takes 0 arguments, such as `public Person()` (notice how I put "Alice" within quotation marks? That's because you didn't define a string called `Alice`, so `Alice` is an unknown object)

Next we have `Mother.Name = "Lucy"`, which won't work, because `Name` is not discoverable. The `class Person` does define a `Name`, but since you didn't specify an access modifier, such as `public` or `private`, `class Program` doesn't even know it exists and thus cannot access it. So you have to use `public string Name` instead of `string Name`. It is also considered to be good style to **always** specify your access modifier. The same applies to `public int Age` and `public int DateOfBirth()` as well.

To know more about access modifiers refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx